# Read more link in media class on Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a limited knowledge  about html/css and I will in following [example](http://www.bootply.com/CD5yejiGD8) display "Read more..." link just after the text instead of under. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work just by moving the link inside the last `</p>` tag. Depending on how you're planning on generating your final content, this is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In example is working but, in my content is more complicated.

Comment: Can you give any details about how your live site complicates the issue?